# Want to combine two sql queries for common results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Want to fetch location_id from location_context table if both of the below condition true for that particular location_id

```
    SELECT location_id 
    FROM location_context 
    WHERE relation_type = '2' 
    AND relation_table = 'locations' 
    AND relation_table_id = '$_GET[cat]' 
    AND is_active = '1'
```

And

```
    SELECT location_id 
    FROM location_context 
    WHERE relation_type = '1' 
    AND relation_table = 'locations' 
    AND relation_table_id = '$_GET[pro]' 
    AND is_active = '1'
```

Comment: Simply add one more AND condition - `SELECT location_id 
FROM location_context 
WHERE relation_type = '2' 
AND relation_table = 'locations' 
AND relation_table_id = '$_GET[cat]' AND relation_table_id = '$_GET[pro]' 
AND is_active = '1'`

Comment: You should always escape client input before parsing into an SQL query to prevent SQL injections.

Comment: I hope you are showing sample code only. the code contains a sql-injection possibility.

Comment: yes, this is a sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use query with `JOIN`:

```
SELECT c1.location_id 
 FROM location_context c1
 JOIN location_context c2 ON c2.location_id = c1.location_id
 -- first query conditions
 WHERE c1.relation_type = '2' 
 AND c1.relation_table = 'locations' 
 AND c1.relation_table_id = '$_GET[cat]' 
 AND c1.is_active = '1'
 -- second query conditions
 AND c2.relation_type = '1' 
 AND c2.relation_table = 'locations' 
 AND c2.relation_table_id = '$_GET[pro]' 
 AND c2.is_active = '1'
```

Comment: please write the query as I never used JOIN before

Comment: @Sandy this is complete query - so try and use it; more info about JOIN: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT L.location_id
FROM location_context L
WHERE L.relation_table = 'locations'
    AND L.is_active = '1'
    AND ((L.relation_type = '2' AND L.relation_table_id = '$_GET[cat]')
        OR (L.relation_type = '1' AND L.relation_table_id = '$_GET[pro]'))
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, using MySQL's [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) function:

```
SELECT location_id 
FROM location_context 
WHERE relation_type IN('1', '2') 
AND relation_table = 'locations' 
AND relation_table_id IN ($_GET['pro'], $_GET['cat']) 
AND is_active = '1'
```

Comment: This is not the same as the original queries. The original ones do not return values where `relation_type=1 and relation_table_id = 'pro'`, this one returns.

Comment: I want to check location_id fetch from first query with the result from the second query. if same location_id exist in both then display